# Linux disable disk cache for a single command

Tags: linux, performance, cache, hard-drive, buffer

Our server is performing decently, but when backups or other scan processes run it will tank the entire server. Something like `clamd` will run and scan many files. While we expect slow performance, it's killing our cache and the end result is we don't get a system that can do anything.

Is there a way to disable disc/disk caching for a single command? The idea would be to run it like this:

```
# ./nocache clamd
```

Then while running `clamd` it would not thrash the primed cache while reading all the files on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be implemented in the program itself. If `clamd` doesn't already do it, you can modify `clamd` to avoid an unnecessarily large cache footprint by adding calls to functions like `posix_fadvise(... POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE)` or `madvise(... MADV_DONTNEED)` (if it memory maps the files). It will still push filesystem metadata out of the cache though. There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: Sad we don't have a user-level way, but thanks for the information. A madman could use a hook or create a process that executes the other code having called this POSIX function (or use LD_LIB)

Comment: Did you ever find a way or code something yourself @KristopherIves?

Answer (score 4):

Its not really the answer you are looking for but we just use ionice for backups and scans so they don't affect the other programs on the server.

```
ionice -c3 clamd
```